# Application working on emulator but crashed on phone WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, crash, gps, geolocation

At start I'm sorry for my English is poor. And this is the only place where i solved the problem.

I have a problem with my application. I write and test it on emulator in VisualStudnio 2012 and It work fine. But when I add aplication in WindowsPhone store and I get to phone. It crashed. I think that problem is in geolocator or something with GPS, because when i use function where my it don't use gps it work. Everywhere where i use geolocator_geopositionchanged it break down and app is terminate. in one of application page i use map control but i gave token and application id but only in class where i use map.

```
       private void maping_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     Microsoft.Phone.Maps.MapsSettings.ApplicationContext.ApplicationId = "id";
     Microsoft.Phone.Maps.MapsSettings.ApplicationContext.AuthenticationToken = "token";
   }
```

Do you have any sugestion or advices?

if you want watching app  there is a link

http://www.windowsphone.com/pl-PL/store/app/opencaching/06bce1e1-16ef-4ebf-ac53-23b4c725f78b

I have geolocator in a few class it's one of them

Geolocator code

```
 if (!tracking)
  {
    gps = new Geolocator();
    gps.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
    gps.ReportInterval = 100;
    gps.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;
  }
  else
  {
    gps.PositionChanged -= geolocator_PositionChanged;
    gps = null;
  }
  tracking = !tracking;
```

Geoposition changed code

```
 void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
        double distance = 0;
        distance = point.GetDistanceTo(new GeoCoordinate(args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude, args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude));

        string asa = Convert.ToInt64(distance).ToString();
        if (asa != null)
        {
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
          {

            TBodleglosc.Text = asa +"m";
            navi.Rotation = 180 + Kierunek(point.Latitude, point.Longitude, args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude, args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude);

          });

        }

}
```

Comment: Please post the geolocator code (initialization and the position changed event handler)

Comment: Is the Location turned on under settings -> Location on the phone? If the location master switch is off, you can't use geolocator (it gives an exception)

Comment: yes Location is turned on at phone settings

Comment: And does it crash when you debug on your phone?

Comment: I can debug app on the phone? but Yes it crash on phone when I lunch app and location is turn on.

Comment: Yes you can. On the top instead set the target to Device. http://puu.sh/9ki9p/48a980cd47.png

Comment: but I can debug on every phone or only developer phone ? because I don't have phone  with WP8 and I debug on friend phone. if yes I try tomorrow.
If you would like try debug and test, I can send you code app.

Comment: You can developer unlock your friend's phone if you want. If not, get in touch with me on Twitter, @ErtaySh

Comment: ok I send you tweet but I first time on tweeter and i don't know is reached. Maybe facebook ? i'm Piotr Olszak. http://www.facebook.com/piotrolszak

Comment: I sent you a Direct Message on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Debug on your device. If that cannot repro, setup a Beta Test app and use that to distribute the app back to yourself for debugging. Sometimes signing breaks things.

Answer (score 0):

I debug at lumia 920 and I have a  problem with convert.toDouble
because there are was , i have . and vice versa

I think that it's connected with phone language
 because in english emulator and Ertay Shashko phone who debug it yesterday it's working fine.

At now application work at phone but doesn't at emulator.

but if i change settings on location and language  apps work but I can't debug because visual studio have error

It's weird .....